# How can I fix the ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have `<button id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>` in my html file and

```js
document.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

in my JS file, but I am recieving this error:

> `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the onclick since you already have a listener anyway. (the actual cause is probably that the function isn't in global scope)

Comment: Open the Network tab, and check the JS file is loaded.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per CherryDT, you can remove the onclick="myFunction()" from the button and do it this way

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```